# I'm not receiving confirmation message to create app

Tags: google-app-engine

My cellphone don't receive sms confirmation message to create an new app. The cellphone provider not listed in https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/supported_carriers#B.

How I do to use google app engine in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is a form linked to on this page:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/sms#error

That you can fill out for your situation.

https://appengine.google.com/waitlist/sms_issues